# VueJs "global" event not being triggered inside my class file

Tags: vuejs2

I have a piece of code (auth.js) that is supposed to be triggered after a user successfully logs in.  But I noticed that 2 lines do not seem working.  it is not tiggered.

this.$axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
and 
this.$eventHub.$emit('userLoggedIn');

is there something i need to do to make both work?  i have set them up to be accessible globally.  i checked out the line:
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
and seems to work fine.

i have tried remove ***this*** word but to no avail.

main.js

```js
import auth from '@/auth'

import axios from 'axios'

Vue.prototype.$axios = axios
Vue.prototype.$auth = auth
Vue.prototype.$eventHub = new Vue();
```

auth.js

```js
class Auth {
    constructor() {
        this.token = null;
        this.user = null;
    }
    login(token, user) {     

        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));

        this.$axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;

        this.token = token;
        this.user = user;

        this.$eventHub.$emit('userLoggedIn');
    }
    check() {
        return !! this.token;
    }
}
export default new Auth();
```

this is the code inside my Login.vue which calls the auth.js login method:

```
        login() {
            let data = {
                email: this.username,
                password: this.password
            };
            this.$axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', data)
            .then(({data}) => {
                if (data.status == 200) {
                    this.$auth.login(data.data.token, data.data.user);
                    this.$router.replace('about');
                } else {
                    // console.log("Error");
                }
            })
            .catch(() => {                    
                //alert(response.data.message);
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` keyword in the Auth class is not pointing to the Vue instance. You can pass the Vue instance as a parameter of login method like this:

```
class Auth {
    constructor() {
        this.token = null;
        this.user = null;
    }
    login(vue, token, user) {     

        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));

        vue.$axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;

        this.token = token;
        this.user = user;

        vue.$eventHub.$emit('userLoggedIn');
    }
    check() {
        return !! this.token;
    }
}
export default new Auth();
```

And then call login method this way:

```
this.$auth.login(this, data.data.token, data.data.user);
```

Comment: this worked for me although i changed it so i only have to pass eventHub.  for axios, i just imported it.  thanks for the help. i'm learning VueJs.